# How to work with $resource in angularjs

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I am trying to get data form this url http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

through $resource below is my resource code

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
 value('version', '0.1').factory('recipes1',['$resource', '$http', '$log', function  ($resource, $http, $log) {
return $resource('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo',{ },{   locate: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat(function(data, headersGetter) {
  // probably be better if you examined the results in here
alert(data);

 })}
});
}]);
```

but i am not getting response. i am getting out put from my controller  as

```
function Resource(value){
"use strict";

    copy(value || {}, this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$http` with promise factory:

See working Demo in <kbd>**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/691/)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, Data) {

    $scope.runMe = function () {

        Data.query($scope.url)
                        .then(function (result) {
                           $scope.data = result;

                        }, function (result) {
                            alert("Error: No data returned");
                        });    
    }

});

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope', 'Data'];

fessmodule.factory('Data', ['$http','$q',  function($http, $q) {

     var data = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo'});

       var factory = {
            query: function (address) { 
                var deferred = $q.defer();              
                deferred.resolve(data);               
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
        return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: ya worked on that one its working but my client need $resource

Comment: Do you use  RESTful server-side data source? if no, i suggest to do not use `$resource`

Comment: its json format u can check the url .i am begner for angularjs and restful services.

Comment: in your case you use `http://api.geonames.org` site to get Json based on provided location lat/longt. I don't see he reason to use `resource`

Comment: it doesn't work for resource or I don't know API of this site. but http.get woks fine and you can load json data as in my example

Comment: can you provide demo for restful service for $resource

Comment: i don't, today use only $http, sorry